# Passing a variable from MY_Controller to a view

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, constructor

On my website I have a 'login prompt' which is visible on every page. I'm using a templating system so this login prompt is present in the header of each page.

When a user is logged in it should show their username and a link to logout. When they're not logged in a link to either login or register is shown.

I have a function in MY_Controller which checks if the user is logged in on every page load which works fine:

```
if($this->is_logged_in()) {
    $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['login_prompt'] = "Hi, " . $this->username . " " . anchor("account/logout", "Logout");
}
```

And in my header.php (the view) I have:

```
<div id="login-prompt" class="transparent">
    <?php
        if (!isset($login_prompt)) $login_prompt = anchor("account/login", "Login") . " or " . anchor("account/register", "register");
        echo $login_prompt;
    ?>
</div>
```

The problem is in my controllers. Here is the constructor of ucp.php, which extends MY_Controller:

```
public $data;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $data['login_prompt'] = $this->data['login_prompt'];
}
```

I would like `$data['login_prompt']` to be available in each method of my controller so it can be passed to the view. However, printing `$data['login_prompt']` gives an error of **`'undefined index'`** and as a result the default "Login or register" message as defined in header.php is always visible.

A typical method in ucp.php would be as follows:

```
function index()
{
    $this->template->build("ucp/ucp_view", $data);
}
```

As you can see the `$data` array should be passed to the view. If I were to define `$data['login_prompt']` in the method itself instead of the constructor such that:

```
function index()
{
    $data['login_prompt'] = $this->data['login_prompt'];
    $this->template->build("ucp/ucp_view", $data);
}
```

The login prompt changes to the correct, logged-in, message. However I'd rather not add this line to every method of every controller in my application.

A similar problem I have found involves simply changing the `$data` array passed to the view to `$this->data`, outlined [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/174906/). This works but breaks several other parts of my application.

I feel like the mistake is something really obvious. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options

You can use a `$this->data` property on your `MY_Controller` and then make sure you pass `$this->data` to all your views

```
// MY_Controller
public $data;

public function __construct()
{
    if($this->is_logged_in()) 
    {
        $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $this->data['login_prompt'] = "Hi, " . $this->username . " " . anchor("account/logout", "Logout");
    }
}
```

And then in our controller..

```
// An example controller. By extending MY_Controller 
// We have the data property available
UcpController extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['Some extra variable'] = 'Foo';
        // Notice we are giving $this->data rather than $data...
        // this means we will have our login prompt included
        // as it is set by the parent class
        $this->template->build("ucp/ucp_view", $this->data);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can set up a global array in `MY_Controller` and then use the `load->vars` method to make the array available to all your views

```
// MY_Controller
public $global_data;

public function __construct()
{
    if($this->is_logged_in()) 
    {
        $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $this->global_data['login_prompt'] = "Hi, " . $this->username . " " . anchor("account/logout", "Logout");

        $this->load->vars($this->global_data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try switching `$data['login_prompt']` to `$login_prompt` in your view.

The error message **'undefined index'** is referring to `'login_prompt'` not being an index in the associative array `$data`.  Code igniter breaks up that array you pass to `$this->load->view()`. Similar to how `extract()` works (php [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), ci [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)).

Answer (score 0):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Scroll about halfway down to "Adding Dynamic Data to the View"

Comment: That's not quite what my issue is. The problem is that $data['login_prompt'] declared in the constructor isn't accessible by any of my methods in the controller, and so isn't passed to the view.